# MapBox didUpdateUserLocation is never called

Tags: swift, mapbox

I'm trying to respond to changes in the user's location in an iOS app using MapBox, but `didUpdateUserLocation` is not being called. Why isn't `didUpdateUserLocation` being called?

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate  {
    @IBOutlet weak var upButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let styleURL = NSURL(string: "mapbox://styles/jmeyers919/cj8w00yxvfrqr2rpehxd47up1") // MGLStyle.darkStyleURL()
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: styleURL as URL?)
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.logoView.isHidden = true
        mapView.attributionButton.isHidden = true
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        // Note that we have changed the center coordinate to New York City for this guide
        // mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 44.0475276, longitude: -123.08927319), zoomLevel: 16, animated: false)
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.upButton)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func mapView(mapView: AnyObject!, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: AnyObject!) {
      print("didUpdateUserLocation")
    }
}
```

Comment: did you request for authorization to track the users location?

Comment: @TNguyen I figured I didn't need to. Mapbox is displaying the correct user location (with `showsUserLocation`), and the user is prompted for permissions, so I assumed MapBox was making the request.

Answer (score 0):

While the `showsUserLocation` property is set to `YES`, this method is called
 whenever a new location update is received by the map view. This method is also
 called if the map view’s user tracking mode is set to
 `MGLUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` and the heading changes, or if it is set
 to `MGLUserTrackingModeFollowWithCourse` and the course changes.

This method is not called if the application is currently running in the background. If you want to receive location updates while running in the
 background, you must use the Core Location framework.